# How to handle errors with imaplib in Python

Tags: python, email, error-handling, imap

I want to write error handling for wen a user would input a wrong password to my script.  I keep changing the code after the except statement, but I can't find out what the right code for the error is.  Am I missing something?

```
import imaplib
import email

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

username = raw_input('USERNAME (email):')
password = raw_input('PASSWORD: ')

    try:
        mail.login(username, password)
        print "Logged in as %r !" % username
    except: 
        imaplib.error
        print "Log in failed."

mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.

fromWho = raw_input('FROM:')

result, data = mail.uid('search', None, '(FROM fromWho)')
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]

print raw_email
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want to catch a certain exception, the exception name in [`try...except`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) clause in Python should be written after `except` keyword:

```
try:
    mail.login(username, password)
    print "Logged in as %r !" % username
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    print "Log in failed."
```

Note that I changed exception name to `imaplib.IMAP4.error`. That's not obvious, but you can find the proper name of the exception by looking in the source code for `imaplib`.

Comment: ... Or by triggering the error without `try`/`except` and examine the error in the traceback.

Comment: @tripleee: It shows `imaplib.error` in the traceback. And when trying to catch `imaplib.error`, `AttributeError` is thrown telling that `imaplib` doesn't have the `error` attribute. So, from the traceback it's completely unclear which exception to catch.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is considered good practice, but the `mail` object is generated from `imaplib.IMAP4` and can be used. 
Using the sample code above:
...
except mail.error:
...

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm annoys me with a warning that the exception isn't specific enough, and typically, I *would* make efforts to be as specific as possible, but looking into this - having the same curiosity - it appears the **imaplib** module only has *one* exception to catch all...

imaplib.IMAP4.error  ...  as @Andrey was quick to answer.